# Matlab: cell to matrix row

Tags: matlab, matrix, cell, readfile

I am trying to convert a text file (comma seperated values) to a matrix in MATLAB. I have been able to fetch the individual lines into cell array but I can't convert those values to a matrix form. The 7X1 cell obtained by reading the line of the file is a row major and has the following values

```
line = 
      '123'
      ''
      '"Foo"'
      [1X27 char]
      '1.01'
      '2.02'
      '0'
```

So, the file is basically a collection of similar lines. Any suggestion as to how can I convert these lines to a matrix form ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: And yes, I would like the output to be of the format row=[123   Foo [1X27 char] 1.01 2.02 0]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `cell2mat` function to create a matrix from your cell (see [MATLAB help page](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html) for details). As your cell is a column vector and you want a row vector, you will have to transpose the cell first.

```
row = cell2mat(line.');
```

If you want to add a space between all elements, here's a way to do this:

```
% Remove all empty fields
line = line(~cellfun(@isempty,line));

% Add a space after each element
line = strcat(line,{' '});

% Now call cell2mat
row = cell2mat(line.');

% and remove space at end
row = strtrim(row);
```

You can use `regexpi` to find quotation marks and remove them.

```
row = row(regexpi(row,'"')) = '';
```

Comment: I tried doing that earlier, but it generates the output as a string '123"Foo"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyza1.012.020' which is not the required format.

Comment: So you need spaces between all entries? And instead of the content of the char array, you need the text '[1x27 char]'?

Comment: No, I need all the entries in a matrix along with the text in the [1x27 char] and not '[1x27 char]'.

Comment: The edited answer does indeed add spaces between the fields but the answer is still a string. I tried extracting the elements of the strings using strread and textscan, but I guess in my case, since there is no pattern in the [1x27 char], I can't use your answer. :(

Comment: In MATLAB a string is an array of characters. So you do have a matrix form. What dou you want to do with `row` afterwards? Maybe then I can help you better.